# Why is my Django form template removing all data after a space?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am using a Django Form to validate a specific sign up page. The Form is set up as so:

```
class MemberForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', required=True)
    password = forms.RegexField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True, regex=r'^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[\S]{8,}$')
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True)
    full_name = forms.CharField(label='Full Name', required=True)
    pref_name = forms.CharField(label='Preferred Name', required=False)
    phone = forms.RegexField(label='Phone', regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', required=True)
    address = forms.CharField(label='Address', required=True)
    city = forms.CharField(label='City', required=True)
    provinces = forms.ChoiceField(label='Provinces', choices=PROVINCE_CHOICES, required=True)
    postal_code = forms.RegexField(label='Postal Code', regex=r'^([A-Z][0-9][A-Z]\s[0-9][A-Z][0-9])$')
    dob = forms.DateField(label='Birthday', required=True)
    occupation = forms.CharField(label='Occupation', required=True)
```

Everything is working fine in this regard, the form accepts everything it should and rejects everything it should. If the form is invalid, I render it again. This is all done in the following view:

```
def create_member(request):
    form = forms.MemberForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            #redirect

    provinces = Provinces.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'party/adminCreateAccount2.html', {'form': form, 'provinces': provinces, 'today': str(now_date())})
```

So, if the form is not valid, I simply stay on the page and reuse the current form. However, when the form reloads, for some reason, all data that has a space will erase everything after the space when it is shown.

For example, if I use 'Test Test' as my full name, then leave everything else blank, when the page reloads, I will only see 'Test'.

My form is displayed using the following custom template:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-row grp-row grp-cells-1 {{ field.html_name }}">
        <div class="field-box l-2c-fluid l-d-4">
            <div class="c-1">
                <label {% if field.field.required %} class="required" {% endif %} for={{ field.html_name }}>{{ field.label }}</label>
            </div>

            <div class="c-2">
                <input class="vTextField" type="text" name={{ field.html_name }} id={{ field.html_name }} value={{ field.data|default_if_none:"" }}>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I tried outputting `{{ field.data|default_if_none:"" }}` right beside the input and it displayed the entire string ('Test test' in our example) so I am completely stumped because I know the correct data is getting passed through. Any idea why its being changed for the input value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is not doing this, your browser is. You need to put the value variable in quotes:

```
value="{{ field.data|default_if_none:"" }}"
```

But really, your shouldn't output fields like this: use Django to do it properly, with just `{{ field }}`.

Comment: Thats what I tried originally, but that always defaulted to display '<input' instead of nothing. Any reason why it might be doing that?

Comment: I meant you should use that instead of the whole `input` tag. You can add the extra html class in the form definition itself.